# How can I find all references to fields defined by a C# 9 record?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-9.0

Repro:

```
public class TestCase
{
    public Boolean MyFieldIsFour(MyRecord myRecord)
    {
        return myRecord.MyField == 4;
    }
}

public record MyRecord(int MyField);
```

Right click `int MyField` and choose `Find All References`.
Visual Studio can't find any references to `MyField`. I would have expected it to find the reference at `myRecord.MyField`. If `MyRecord` is changed to a `class` then Visual Studio has no problems finding the reference as expected.

Is this a bug in Visual Studio? How can I actually find references now with `record`s?

Comment: `int MyField` is the constructor parameter, so you were finding all references to the that, not the associated `MyField` *property*.

Comment: I wouldn't call that a bug. Visual Studio just hasn't yet been given the ability to link primary constructor parameters to their associated properties when finding references.  Someone has to take the time to add that functionality.

Comment: Which VS version are you using so far?

Comment: Given that all properties are required and immutable, how many times do you need to find references to *only* `MyProperty`? The property can only be set by the constructor, so if you want to find where it's set, you only need to look for constructor calls.

Comment: It wouldn't find `with` expressions where the property is being initialized on the new instance.

Comment: Ok so it's actually searching for the constructor properties. But how can I get it to search for references to the corresponding (generated) properties?

Comment: Write a temporary method with `new MyRecord(4) with { MyField = 5 }` and use Find All References on the property in the initializer expression. It's a throw-away method just for this purpose. You would *never* write anything like that normally, throwing away the first instance just change one property in the clone instance, but it gives you a mention of the property you can use. It's not great, but it'll work.

Comment: And it's important to get the terminology correct because I think that's leading to the misunderstanding: it was searching the constructor *parameters*. The properties are not textually addressable in the type's declaration (at least not the way you declared it) and that's why this was an issue.

Comment: You *could* add explicit property declarations and then they would be addressable in the declaration: `public record MyRecord(int MyField) { public int MyField { get; init; } }` Understandably, that kind of defeats the purpose of using a `record` type so I don't blame you for not wanting to do that.

Comment: Did you raise an issue at microsoft? Not being able to search for the usage of record members without dirty hacks is seriously annoying and not the UX they should be aiming for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug (*or not implemented feature if you want call it that way*) in Roslyn.

The semantics around `record`s is a mess. See [this feedback](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Find-all-references-does-not-work-for-re/1612150), [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/44559), [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/44560), [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/50450), [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/57873)

Comment: I guess this is the answer for now. Thanks for the links.